# Symfony2 Form, don't match the Entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'am follow the '[how to](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html)' implement registration form in Symfony 2
I created the Registration and RegistrationType, like the tutorial.

I created the User entity and UserType as well.
Everything is equal, but I recived an Exception submiting the form.

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to My\Bundle\Form\Model\Registration::setUser() must be an instance of My\Bundle\Entity\User, array given
```

Becasue in the Registration.php:

```
public function setUser(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

`$user` is not a `User`, is an `array`. This array have the inputs data:

```
array (size=2)
'email' => string 'email@email.com' (length=15)
'password' => string 'password' (length=8)
```

**Why the form is not 'matching' the entity?**

In my UserType form I configured the data_class:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'        => 'My\Bundle\Entity\User',
    ));
}
```

UserType:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email', 'text')
        ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
            'first_name'    => 'password',
            'second_name'   => 'confirm',
            'type'          => 'password'
        ))
        ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'        => 'My\Bundle\Entity\User',
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'user';
}
}
```

RegistrationType:

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('user', new UserType());
    $builder->add('terms', 'checkbox', array('property_path' => 'termsAccepted'));
    $builder->add('Register', 'submit');
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'registration';
}
}
```

Registration:

```
class Registration {

/**
 * @Assert\Type(type="My\Bundle\Entity\User")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\True()
 */
protected $termsAccepted;



public function setUser(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

public function getTermsAccepted()
{
    return $this->termsAccepted;
}

public function setTermsAccepted($termsAccepted)
{
    $this->termsAccepted = (bool) $termsAccepted;
}
}
```

The Action:

```
public function registerProcessAction(Request $request){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), new Registration());

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $registration = $form->getData();
        $em->persist($registration->getUser());
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute(...);
    }
    else{
        die('invalid');
    }
```

User entity:

```
/**
 * Class User
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 */
class User{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max = 4096)
 */
private $password;

/** GETTERS **/
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/** SETTERS **/

public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    return $this;
}

}
```

Comment: You said it - it doesn't match because it's an array, and the method expects `User` object. What does your `$user` variable contains? Can you edit your post and show how you populate that?

Comment: @Artamiel, I updated the question adding the `var_dump` of the `$user` variable. I don't populate this variable, I supose that is a thing of the Symfony Form code. Thanks

Comment: pls show the content of your action where you are bind an user from the form

Comment: Can you also post your User class?

Comment: @KonstantinPereyaslov question update

Comment: Are you using Symfony 2.6+? Before that it was `setDefaultOptions()` instead of `configureOptions()`

Comment: @KonstantinPereyaslov That's it! Now I update to 2.7.0 and use `configureOptions()` function. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before Symfony 2.6 this method was `setDefaultOptions()`, not `configureOptions()`. So the solution would be to upgrade to Symfony 2.6/2.7 or read documentation for your version.